# How to save add button dynamically in android?

Tags: android

The code should add a button dynamically when the user needs it.
When an users click on `addService` this code takes (a name for button and a value to use in the intent for this button) from a second Activity, then adds the  button dynamically in this Activity with the name and intent and the user can click it for service.

How to save  the button dynamically added by the user?

```
Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
btn.setText(buttonName);
layout.addView(btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String phone = serviceNum;
        Intent e = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
        startActivity(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the save button in your layout, then hide it before the view loads.  When the user performs the action, simply unhide the button.  The layout should handle it automatically for you.

Comment: btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: And the code to unhide the button: btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Comment: this way ok, but when user close the app then open Can not find the button
Because the button is hidden due

Comment: Look at the activity lifecycle on this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html.  You're going to have to save the state of the program when the user quits, then reload it on return.

Comment: Consider if you want View.GONE or View.INVISIBLE. Both these codes will make the button invisible, the difference is that with GONE, it won't take layout space, contrary to INVISIBLE.

Switching from VISIBLE to GONE and vice versa might change your layout.